# SDK platform update: unable to stop ADB

Tags: android, sdk

i am totally new to android development and currently i am dealing with this problem coming from my SDK when i tried to update some stuffs.

There is this message that says "Stopping ADB..." and it stays there for like ever without doing anything.

Is there a thing i am doing wrong?

**Screen shot**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is coming from my antivirus

what i did was: disable my antivirus and re-run the update and everything was fine this time